# Reload treeview with new root nodes and new item source

Tags: c#, treeview, uwp-xaml

If I load the treeview the first time with nodes and items, after initialize components, the treeview works without problems.
If the same treeview will be cleared with

```
TreeView.RootNodes.Clear()
```

for refreshing with new nodes and items, it gives the follow exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException - A method was called at an unexpected time.
```

Moreover, the rootnodes property has no setter..

How is it possible to refresh the treeview with new nodes and items?

Thanks for answering

Comment: You can try to create a `TreeView` with binding, [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#tree-view-using-data-binding) shows the relevant code. By binding the data set to `TreeView.ItemsSource`, you can directly add and delete data items to the collection instead of operating the `TreeViewNode`. It is not clear that you modify the specific code of `TreeViewNode`, you can try the binding method first, if this does not solve your problem, you can provide a minimum runable demo so that we can analyze your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for vour advise. It runs now, more simple, without operations on the root node of the tree view.